# Export the coordinates of STL object

Tags: export, import, 3d-printing

Hi I currently have a STL file of a 3D object

Is it possible for me to obtain the coordinates of the object so that I can just input that into Autodesk Inventor

Comment: I don't think that *Mathematica* is the best tool for this job. Take a look e.g. at [this discussion on methods to import STL to Inventor](https://www.thingiverse.com/groups/autodesk-inventor/topic:517). The general suggestion is to either use a plugin to enable Inventor to read and process STL files, or to go through a third application first for conversion.

Comment: Regarding closure: While *Mathematica* may not be the optimal tool out of the box, someone around may supply a workable solution, so I would not close unless this is a duplicate. *Mathematica* is suboptimal for many tasks, which nevertheless get done with it.

Answer (score 3):

An example from the [STL](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/STL.html) documentation that returns the coordinates of an object:

```
Import["ExampleData/spikey.stl", "VertexData"]
(*
  {{-0.294944, 0.907744, 1.2494}, {0., 0., 0.951057},
   ...
   {-1.2494, 0.907744, -0.294944}, {-1.2494, -0.907744, -0.294944}}
*)
```